# Unix script to delete file if it contains single line

Tags: unix

Consider I have a file abcde.txt which may contain one or more lines of text. I want a script that will DELETE the file if it contains single line.

Something like, `if 'wc -l abscde.txt' = 1 then rm abscde.txt`

My system : Solaris

Comment: Do you want to delete the file even if it just has a blank line?

Comment: 1. It's BASH shesll 2. yes, if file is blank then delete too. But in my case it will always have atleast single line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a simple bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

LINECOUNT=`wc -l abscde.txt | cut -f1 -d' '`

if [[ $LINECOUNT == 1 ]]; then
   rm -f abscde.txt
fi
```

Comment: This solution didn't work on solaris for me.  The cut command doesn't deal with the extra spaces in front of the output from wc.  I used the following instead `wc -l abscde.txt | awk '{print $1}'`

Answer (score 0):

```
delifsingleline () {
    if [ $(cat $1 | wc -l) = "1" ]
    then
        echo "Deleting $1"
        echo "rm $1"
    fi
}
```

Lightly tested on `zsh`. Should work on `bash` as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is (mostly) just a reformat of Ben's answer:

```
wc -l $PATH | grep '^1 ' > /dev/null && rm -f $PATH
```